# Pass data between screens in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have a button in one screen and data items that i've retrieved from a mysql database. The button is able to print the data items to the terminal in the first screen, but I'm having difficulty printing the data_items in the other screen. How do I 'get' the items? I'm learngin kivy so i must've missed something but I've searched everywhere.
Here's the code:

```
def item_button_callback(self, instance):
        item_data = instance.item_data  # Retrieve the item data from the button's property
        print(f"Clicked item data: {item_data}")
        screen_manager = self.manager
        edit = EditScreen(item_data=item_data)
        screen_manager.switch_to(edit)


class EditScreen(Screen):
    def get_stuff(self, item_data): 
        print({item_data})
```

The Result: a type error: TypeError: Properties ['item_data'] passed to **init** may not be existing property names. Valid properties are ['center', 'center_x', 'center_y', 'children', 'cls', 'disabled', 'height', 'ids', 'manager', 'motion_filter', 'name', 'opacity', 'parent', 'pos', 'pos_hint', 'right', 'size', 'size_hint', 'size_hint_max', 'size_hint_max_x', 'size_hint_max_y', 'size_hint_min', 'size_hint_min_x', 'size_hint_min_y', 'size_hint_x', 'size_hint_y', 'top', 'transition_progress', 'transition_state', 'width', 'x', 'y']

Terminal in first screen prints: Clicked item data: ('Murder', 'Retro', '', ''), because the data is data from rows in the database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exchanging Variables between Screens in kivy python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27758126/exchanging-variables-between-screens-in-kivy-python)