# Kivy Using a ScreenManager from kv file

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing a kivy program/game. I've made one before, but was only 1 screen in total. I've started developing a new program with ideas of implementing a `Screen Manager`. I managed to build the `Screen Manager` inside of the python file, but it wasn't suitable for my long term usage, and I wanted to try my hand at a `Screen Manager` from the `.kv file`.

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated, not sure what I missed. I looked at this questionv([Kivy - Screen Manager - Accessing attribute in other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27362687/kivy-screen-manager-accessing-attribute-in-other-class)), and pieced together what I thought was right, but still can't get a screen to load - I feel this is a simple answer and I'm being blind...

main.py;

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class NewGameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LoadGameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ASCIILifeApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ASCIILifeApp().run()
```

ASCIILife.kv;

```
#: kivy 1.9
#: import ScreenManager kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#: import Screen kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager
#: import NewGameScreen screen
#: import LoadGameScreen screen

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager
    #transition: FadeTransition()
    MenuScreen:
        id: menu_screen
        name: 'MenuScreen'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
    NewGameScreen:
        id: newgame_screen
        name: 'NewGameScreen'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
    LoadGameScreen: 
        id: loadgame_screen
        name: 'LoadGameScreen'
        manager: 'screen_manager'

<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'ASCII Life'
            font_size: 50
        Button:
            text: 'New Game'
            font_size: 30
            on_release: app.root.current = 'newgame'
        Button:
            text: 'Load Game'
            font_size: 30
            on_release: app.root.current = 'loadgame'
        Button:
            text: 'Settings'
            font_size: 30
            on_release: app.root.current = 'something'
<NewGameScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: 'Game Length in Days'
                font_size: 30
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                ToggleButton:
                    text: '100'
                    state: 'down'
                    group: 'newgame_days'
                    font_size: 30
                ToggleButton:
                    text: '200'
                    group: 'newgame_days'
                    font_size: 30
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                ToggleButton:
                    text: '365'
                    group: 'newgame_days'
                    font_size: 30
                ToggleButton:
                    text: '3650'
                    group: 'newgame_days'
                    font_size: 30
            ToggleButton:
                text: 'Unlimited'
                group: 'newgame_days'
                font_size: 30
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            size_hint: (1, .5)
            Label:
                text: 'Difficulty (Score Multiplier)'
                font_size: 30
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Easy (x1)'
                    state: 'down'
                    group: 'newgame_difficulty'
                    font_size: 30
                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Medium (x2.5)'
                    group: 'newgame_difficulty'
                    font_size: 30
                ToggleButton:
                    text: 'Hard (x5)'
                    group: 'newgame_difficulty'
                    font_size: 30
<LoadGameScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'load a game'
            font_size: 30
        Widget:
            canvas:
                Ellipse:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: 'Menu'
                font_size: 30
                on_release: app.root.current = 'menu'
            Button:
                text: 'text'
                font_size: 30
```

Edit: Truncated kv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was using a builder to build the kv file. Knew it was something simple. File below;

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class NewGameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LoadGameScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

buildKV = Builder.load_file("ASCIILife.kv")

class ASCIILifeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return buildKV

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ASCIILifeApp().run()
```

Comment: If you call the file 'asciilife.kv', it will be loaded automatically.

Comment: Ahhhh I did think that the kv file should load automatically, if you remove the word 'app'. I didn't realise it was case sensitive. Thanks!

Comment: You might also find it easier to do #:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition. This makes the FadeTransition() function available to the kv file, without having to load with Builder.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Chazara's findings:

**Either** rename the kv code file according to the naming convension:

> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in
>   lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’.

From the documentation:[how to load kv language](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv)

**Or** just make it explicit with the builder function:

```
Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Chazara's findings even more: 
i tested the code from Chazara with kivy 1.10.1dev0 and Python 3.6; i got an error saying:

```
 kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "something".
```

to fix it, i changed in the .kv file

```
[...]    
Button:
   text: 'New Game'
   font_size: 30
   on_release: app.root.current = 'newgame'
[...]
```

to:

```
[...]    
Button:
   text: 'New Game'
   font_size: 30
   on_release: app.root.current = 'NewGameScreen'
[...]
```

it references the name of NewGameScreen given in the ScreenManager

```
    ScreenManager:
[...]
         NewGameScreen:
            id: newgame_screen
            *name: 'NewGameScreen'*
            manager: 'screen_manager'
```