# Kivy kv file is not working

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have the same issue like described in this theme [kv incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34748579/kivy-using-a-screenmanager-from-kv-file/38109098#38109098). When I use Builder and load the kv file I have normal working app. But when I try to use autoload kv file I have only black screen. Could someone explain me why? Thanks for any help.

My code. main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition


class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass


class AnotherScreen(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

kv file.    test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.9.1

#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:

<MainScreen>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "other"
        text: "Next Screen"
        font_size: 50

<AnotherScreen>:
    name: "other"
    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = "main"
        text: "Prev Screen"
        font_size: 50
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `kv` file, you define `ScreenManagement` to be the root element with its associated screens. But in `build`, you return a newly created `ScreenManagement` object, which will not have any children defined.

Solution:
Define `build` as

```
def build(self):
    pass
```

*or* change the definition of `ScreenManagement` in the kv file to

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:
```

so this will apply to *all* new `ScreenManagement` objects.

Comment: Thanks zeeMonkeez . You helped me a lot. Sorry for trivial question.

Comment: @Velidan it's a subtlety easy to miss, and therefore actually a useful question. It took me a moment to figure out...

Answer (score 0):

you can also add:

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
```

then change:

```
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass
```

to this:

```
class ScreenManagement(screenManager):
    mainscreen = ObjectProperty(None)
    anotherscreen = ObjectProperty(None)
```

then in your .kv file you want to change this:

```
ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    MainScreen:
    AnotherScreen:
```

to this:

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    mainscreen: mainscreen
    anotherscreen: anotherscreen
```

then for your MainScreen add and id like so:

```
<MainScreen>:
    id: mainscreen
```

and do the same for you AnotherScreen.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of your Python and the version of Pygame you're using. I got that problem and my issue came from the version of Pygame.